# Python typing. Function that narrows return type according to input list of types TypeVar(bound=Union[A,B], covariant=True)

Tags: python, typing, narrowing, pyright, type-variables

Today I've been reading into the Liskov's Substitution Principle and reading various docs/blogs on covariance/contravariance after experiencing the following problem.

I want a function which narrows the returned type according to the provided list of allowed types. In the below example, `A`, `B`, and `C` all subclass `Base`. I want a function which can return an instance of A or B, but not C. And furthermore the return type can be narrowed to just `A` or just `B` depending on if you provide a collection of allowed types.

Consider the following valid Python 3.8 code explaining this:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from collections.abc import Collection
from typing import TypeVar, Union
from typing_extensions import Self


class Base:
    @classmethod
    def from_db(cls: type[Self]) -> Self:
        return cls()

class A(Base): ...


class B(Base): ...


class C(Base): ...


ItemUnions = Union[A, B]
Items_co = TypeVar("Items_co", bound=ItemUnions, covariant=True)

items: Collection[Base] = [A(), B(), C()]


def get_item(allowed_items: Collection[type[Items_co]] = frozenset((A, B))) -> Items_co:
    for item in items:
        if type(item) in allowed_items:
            return item  # error 1 below

    return A.from_db()  # error 2 below
```

This function successfully narrows the returned type using the bound TypeVar:

```py
a = get_item(allowed_items={A, B})  # revealed type of a is A | B
b = get_item(allowed_items={A})  # revealed type of b is A
c = get_item()  # revealed type of c is A | B
```

But results in the following pyright errors:

- Error 1: `Type "Base" cannot be assigned to type "Items_co@get_item"`
- Error 2: `Type "A" cannot be assigned to type "Items_co@get_item"`

I can of course wrap the returned type in a `typing.cast(Items_co, ...)`, but this is a messy solution and would favour one which avoids using a cast. I just can't seem to find one. There's no way I can seem to tell pyright to narrow the return type of the function to the type variable `Items_co`. I've tried things like:

- `assert item is Items_co`
- `assert item in allowed_items`

Thanks for any help.